# Htaccess rule to resolve the 404 error when host name is repeating twice

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

We are using unlimited sitemap generator to generate a xml sitemap and it takes all urls in the site. Unfortunately there is an error noticed in webmaster's crawl error section. There are a huge number of urls fetching by sitemap as duplicate urls.

For eg:if actual url is "http://www.example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10"

The sitemap fetch this url and also a duplicate url returning 404 error as"http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com:80/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10"

(This is only an example url.)

All other urls listed in the sitemap are correct.The issue is with forum section only.(Using phpbb for forum).

Can any one suggest any valid htaccess rule to avoid this 404 .
I want to redirect all patterns like  'http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com:80/forum/....' to 'http://www.example.com/forum/.........'

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+.+?(/forum/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

**Explanation:**

`%{THE_REQUEST}` represents  the original request as received by Apache which in your case may look like: `GET /http://www.example.com:80/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&‌​st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10 HTTP/1.0`

Breaking down my regex: `^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+.+?(/forum/[^\s]+)` now

1. This part of regex `^[A-Z]{3,}\s` matches `'GET '` part of input.
2. This part of regex `/+.+?` matches `/http://www.example.com:80` part of input (`.+?` is     reluctant match until next part of regex i.e. `/forum/` starts.
3. This part of regex `/forum/` matches literal `/forum/` part of input.
4. This part of regex `[^\s]+` matches `/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&‌​st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10` part of input. (until a space is found).
5. `(/forum/[^\s]+)` is putting `/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&‌​st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10` in match group #1 (denoted by `%1` in RewriteRule later)

Then `RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]` is executing when above RewriteCond is true. This rule then redirects the request to `%1` captured above.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this answer bit more. ie 
My source url is http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com:80/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10 and i want to redirect this url to http://www.example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10. so where I can give this source.

Comment: Once you have above .htaccess code in place it will redirect `http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com:80/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10` to `http://www.example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=221&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=10` Test it out, if it works I will add an explanation.

Comment: Great thanks anubhava. This answer worked.I am very new to regular expression, if u don't mind small clarification expecting on this rule.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Adding explanation with my answer.

Comment: Yes. Clear. Thank u very much for your effort and help on this critical situation.